# Render problems cardstackview in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have installed CardStackView 2.3.4 but when I use it it gives me render problems

Anyone like me , can help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "render problems"? Does it crash when you run the app? is the preview broken?

Comment: problem when i design, and the preview broken @JustSightseeing